# Creating shopping cart with multiple javascript input

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating a product display with add to shopping cart in session.
the product has different sizes, quantity, and SKU.

I would like to see: 
If a customer selects the size, that the hidden inputs will be filled with:

- Selected size
- SKU equal to selected size

```
<div class="sc-item <?=$itemDisable;?>">
    <input type="radio" name="variatie_maat" value="<?=$order_list['maat'];?>" onclick="myFunction('<?=$order_list['prijs'];?>');" id="<?=$order_list['maat'];?>-maat" <?=$disableValue;?>>
    <label for="<?=$order_list['maat'];?>-maat"><?=$order_list['maat'];?></label>
    <input style="display:none;" value="<?=$order_list['prijs'];?>" id="prijs-<?=$order_list['prijs'];?>" name="variatie_prijs[]">
</div>
```

Hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="productPrijs" id="newPrice" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="SKU" value="<?=$row['SKU'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?=$row['quantity'];?>" />

<input type="hidden" name="naam" value="<?=$row['title'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?=$_GET['id'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?=$row['image_1'];?>" />
```

Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [prijs] => 10,00
            [maat] => M
            [aantal] => 12
            [SKU] => tshirt-FE-m
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [prijs] => 20,00
            [maat] => L
            [aantal] => 17
            [SKU] => tshirt-FE-l
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [prijs] => 30,00
            [maat] => XL
            [aantal] => 21
            [SKU] => tshirt-FE-xl
        )

)
```

Javascript showing selected value for the customer

```
<script>
    function myFunction(id) {
      var x = document.getElementById("prijs-" + id).value;

      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "€ " + x;
      document.getElementById("newPrice").value = x;
      document.getElementById("quantity").innerHTML = "Beschikbaarheid: <span>Op voorraad</span>";
      document.getElementById("SKU").innerHTML = "SKU: <?=$order_list['SKU'];?>";

    }
</script>
```

My add to cart.php

```
<?php

//ADD TO CART
if (isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
{
    $index = false;

    if(!isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
        $index = false;
    }
    else {

        foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $key => $value) {

            if($value["item_id"] == $_GET["id"] && $value['item_size'] == $_POST['maat']) {
                $index = $key;
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    if($index !== false) {
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$index]['item_quantity']++;
    }
    else {
        // create new entry in the session shopping_cart
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][] = array(
            'item_id'       => $_GET['id'],
            'item_name'     => $_POST['naam'],
            'item_price'    => $_POST['productPrijs'],
            'item_image'    => $_POST['image'],
            'item_size'     => $_POST['variatie_maat'],
            'item_quantity' => $_POST['aantal'],
          //  'item_color'    => $_POST["product-1-color"],
            'item_sku'      => $_POST["SKU"],
         );
        header('Location: https://' . $CONFIG::get_templatesettings('WEB_ROOT') . '/winkelwagen?toegevoegd=1');
        exit;
    }

}

//REMOVE FROM CART
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    if($_GET['action'] == 'delete'){
        foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $value){
            if($value['item_id'] == $_GET['id']){
                unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]);
                header('Location: https://' . $CONFIG::get_templatesettings('WEB_ROOT') . '/winkelwagen?verwijderd=1');
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Do not store prices into hidden fields if you don't want the customer to change the price or buy free products - Just store the procuct id and look up in your db for anything that is related to your product

Comment: Okay, than i can probably do it with the SKU, take price from the SKU

Comment: _...take price from the SKU..._ exactly!

Comment: But the question is, how can i store the SKU of the selected size in the input

Comment: _But the question is..._ Use a form, post it to the target page, parse the sent inputs for sku...

Comment: I'm using a form post, but i need to get the values of the selected size.  Now the problem is, that if customer click add to cart, it only gives the size and quantity. als i want to add the SKU

Comment: _I'm using a form post..._ Well I don't see any forms here

Comment: [link]https://webshop.webbouwerz.nl/product-bekijken?id=147

Comment: You can see if you select a size, javascript change the price in de H3 tag, below i want to let display the SKU, and also store it in the value of the hidden input,

Comment: Please post "relevant" code into your question - It seems your approach is not correct at all. Have a look at tutorials,, examples for a better understanding. In a good design you only need to know the unique SKU and then to find the related attributes to this SKU e.g. sizecode, colorcode, price, saleprice, etc...

Comment: Okay, thanks for your replies, i'll take a look at tutorials.

Comment: Take a look at [this one](https://www.allphptricks.com/simple-shopping-cart-using-php-and-mysql/) but there are also many more examples